# Understanding adiabatic elimination in three-level system coupled to EM field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, quantum-optics, time-evolution, adiabatic

I am having some difficulties understanding the "adiabatic elimination" in the context of atomic physics.
In particular, consider a three-level system with states labeled by $|g_1\rangle$, $|g_2\rangle$ and $|e\rangle$ coupled to a classical electromagnetic field which stimulates the transitions $|g_1\rangle \leftrightarrow |e\rangle$ and $|g_2\rangle \leftrightarrow |e\rangle$.
After some work, we can write the Hamiltonian in the rotating wave approximation and in a suitable frame of reference where it is time independent as
$$
H = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\delta\omega_1 - \Delta & 0 & \Omega_1 \\
0 & \delta\omega_2 - \Delta & \Omega_2 \\
\Omega_1 & \Omega_2 & -\Delta
\end{array}
\right),
$$
where $\delta\omega_i$ are the field detunings, $\Omega_i$ the Rabi couplings and $\Delta = (\delta\omega_1+\delta\omega_2)/2$. The basis that I have used is $\{|g_1\rangle, |g_2\rangle, |e\rangle\}$.
Now this leads to a Schrodinger equation for the state $\psi_{g_1}|g_1\rangle+\psi_{g_2}|g_2\rangle + \psi_e|e\rangle$ that, for what concerns the $|e\rangle$ component of the state, reads
$$
i\partial_t \psi_{e} = -\Delta \psi_e + \Omega_1 \psi_{g_1} + \Omega_2 \psi_{g_2}.
$$

So far so good, but now here's my problem: the typical assumption to obtain an effective two-level dynamics from here is to set $\partial_t\psi_e=0$, which is called **adiabatic elimination** and apparently it holds under the assumption $\delta \omega_1 \approx \delta\omega_2$ (or similarly $|\delta\omega_i-\Delta| \ll \Delta$).
However I totally don't understand why we can set $\partial_t\psi_e=0$. I understand that we are interested in slow dynamics and we want to get rid of fast oscillations; but how does this lead to  $\partial_t\psi_e=0$?
Can anyone please explain this subtle point to me?

Comment: what are $\psi_j$ here?  Coefficients?  Are they time-dependent? Where does the linear combination $\psi_e \vert e\rangle+\ldots$ come from?

Comment: closely related to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516306/36194)

Comment: Yes, $\psi_j$ are time dependent coefficients expressing a generic state and $|g_1\rangle$, $|g_2\rangle$, $|e\rangle$ are the basis states used to write the Hamiltonian explicitly.

Comment: Actually the adiabatic elimination assumes that the wavefunctions are (relatively) varying slowly enough to ignore their time derivatives, i.e. $\dot{\psi} \approx 0$. Nevertheless, in order to carry the computations, one will set $\dot{\psi} = 0$ in practice.

Comment: Thanks @Abezhiko, this is fine, but why can we safely state that $\partial_t\psi_e$ is smaller than all the other terms in the equation? Also, isn't $\psi_e(t)$ rapidly oscillating, so that actually $\partial_t \psi_e$ should be large instead?

Comment: One thing that I thought is the following: based on the exact solution of the problem we have $\psi_e = \psi_e^{\text{slow}} + \psi_e^{\text{fast}}$, where $\psi_e^{\text{slow}}$ is oscilating slowly compared to $\psi_{g_i}$ while $\psi_e^{\text{fast}}$ contains the fast dynamics. Then we neglect fast dynamics completely and substitute $\psi_e \to \psi_e^{\text{slow}}$. By definition then we can state $\partial_t \psi_e^{\text{slow}} \approx 0$; but I don't know if this makes any sense